# Ubuntu 20.04 android studio slow startup?

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu

With ubuntu 20.04 released, I thought I'd switch from windows for android app development,
So I did a fresh install on my SSD, then installed android studio from the snap store ,but found
that it takes a lot of time to startup compared to windows, which I expected to be slower.
On Ubuntu 20.04 android studio starts in a full 30 seconds while on windows it only takes 5-7 seconds, So I decided to uninstall it, and download from the official site, but the result was the same. Am I doing something wrong or what ? cause i saw in other videos it starts just as fast on windows, maybe a Ubuntu 20.04 issue I don't know please help if you have any insights

Comment: I have the same issue. Maybe we have to open a ticket ?

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt install appmenu-gtk2-module` and restart fixes it for me, it now starts up instantly. I'm using the snap version, didn't try the .deb.